# Make bash use external `time` command rather than shell built-in

Tags: bash, shell-builtin, time-utility

How can I make bash use time binary (/usr/bin/time) by default instead of the shell keyword?

`which time` returns `/usr/bin/time`
`type time` returns `time is a shell keyword`
Running `time` is obviously executing the shell keyword:

```
$ time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ /usr/bin/time
Usage: /usr/bin/time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
   [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
   [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
```

`enable -n time` returns `bash: enable: time: not a shell builtin`

Comment: See also my very-closely-related question I just asked, before seeing this question: [How to pass optional arguments to `time` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/699799/114401)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `command` shell built-in to bypass the normal lookup process and run the given command as an external command regardless of any other possibilities (shell built-ins, aliases, etc.). This is often done in scripts which need to be portable across systems, although probably more commonly using the shorthand `\` (as in `\rm` rather than `command rm` or `rm`, as especially the latter may be aliased to something not known like `rm -i`).

```
$ time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ command time
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
$
```

This can be used with an alias, like so:

```
$ alias time='command time'
$ time
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
$
```

The advantage of this over e.g. `alias time=/usr/bin/time` is that you aren't specifying the full path to the `time` binary, but instead falling back to the usual path search mechanism.

The `alias` command itself can go into e.g. ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc (the latter is global for all users on the system).

**For the opposite case** (forcing use of the shell built-in in case there's an alias defined), you'd use something like `builtin time`, which again overrides the usual search process and runs the named shell built-in. The bash man page mentions that this is often used in order to provide custom `cd` functionality with a function named `cd`, which in turn uses the builtin `cd` to do the real thing.

Comment: You can also inquire where a particular command is coming from using the command `type -a <cmd>`.

Comment: `command` doesn't bypass builtins (except in `zsh` when not emulating other shells). It bypasses functions and that's the main reason for its existence. Its second role is to remove the _special_ in _special builtins_. It bypasses aliases and keywords only because those are only expanded in first position (in `zsh` for instance, it doesn't bypass global aliases). There is no `time` bash builtin. `time` is a keyword so you can do for instance `time { foo; bar; }`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas By all means feel free to edit that into the answer to provide a more accurate description. `command` works in this particular case, as exemplified, but obviously a correct answer is better than a half-right one.

Comment: The last part of your answer is wrong. time is not a shell builtin, but rather a shell keyword. `builtin time` doesn't work.

Comment: similar to command would be to just quote it: `'time' echo test`

Answer (score 11):

There is a shortcut in bash to sidestep keywords, without having to specify a path or use another builtin like `command`:  Escape it with a backslash.

```
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ \time
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
```

Personally, I find this more readable and safer, as this is possible:

```
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ alias command=echo
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ command time
time
```

Comment: Note that any form of quoting or anything that makes it *not* the token `time` will do: `ti\me`, `'time'`, `ti""me`, `ti${-##*}me`, `${-+time}`... That applies to any shell keyword.

Comment: Best PS1 I've seen yet.

Comment: @maxywb Also, it's not just decorative - if the last command failed, the happy face turns into a red `(x_x)`

Answer (score 5):

The general solutions for built-ins (for example test) are <sup>[1]</sup>:

- use `env` (all shells)

  ```
  $ env test
  external test
  ```
- disable the builtin (only bash and zsh):

  ```
  $ test 1 = 1 && echo "yes"
  yes
  $ enable -n test        ### for bash. Re-enable with "enable test".
  $ disable test          ### for zsh. Re-enable with "enable test".
  $ test
  external test
  ```
- use any slash `/` to call the command (all shells):

  ```
  $ test 1 = 1 && echo "yes"
  yes 
  $ ~/bin/test
  external test
  ```
- make an alias (fails inside a bash script, except if `shopt -s expand_aliases` is used):

  ```
  $ alias test='~/bin/test'             ### remove with 'unalias test'.
  $ test
  external test
  ```

#### But time is not a builtin.

The word `time` is a "Reserved word", not a command and neither a built-in.
That enable this solutions:

- Quote the word. This does not work with built-ins.
  Many forms of quoting work:  `\time` `"time"` `'time'` `ti\me` `ti"me"`, etc.

  ```
  $  time

  real    0m0.000s
  user    0m0.000s
  sys     0m0.000s

  $ \time
  Usage: /usr/bin/time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
         [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
         [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
  ```

  This is useful to bypass an alias. Even if `test` is aliased, `\test` will execute the PATHed command (or the builtin if it has not been disabled).
- Use the builtin `command` (this does not work with built-ins):

  ```
  $ command time
  ```
- As above for built-ins, using any slash `/` works:

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/time
  ```
- As above for built-ins, an alias also work here:

  ```
  $ alias time='command time'
  $ alias time='/usr/bin/time'
  ```

<sup>[1] Lets assume there is an external executable in `~/bin/test` that prints "external test". And further: lets assume that `~/bin` is ahead of `/bin` in the active PATH.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `enable` command to disable certain built-ins.

```
$ enable -n kill
```

However `time` is a keyword so this won't work.

```
$ builtin time
bash: builtin: time: not a shell builtin
```

So you're left with creating an alias to override it:

```
$ alias time=/usr/bin/time
```

Comment: nope. time is a shell keyword, not a shell builtin. I was just about to edit my question to say that enable -n does not work when I saw you had answered.

Answer (score 2):

Drop this into your `~/.bashrc`:

`alias time=/usr/bin/time`