# Write output of `time` in a file, why are parentheses needed?

Tags: io-redirection, shell-builtin

`time` writes to `stderr`, so one would assume that adding `2>&1` to the command line should route its output to `stdout`. But this does not work:

```
test@debian:~$ cat file 
one two three four
test@debian:~$ time wc file > wc.out 2>&1

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
test@debian:~$ cat wc.out 
 1  4 19 file
```

Only with parentheses it works:

```
test@debian:~$ (time wc file) > wc.out 2>&1
test@debian:~$ cat wc.out 
 1  4 19 file

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Why are parentheses needed in this case? Why isn't `time wc` interpreted as *one single* command?

Comment: Note that the results will differ depending on whether `time` is the shell keyword, or `/usr/bin/time`. There might be several sets of descriptors involved here (the shell's, and those attached to a `time` process). And let's not forget about those implied by the `()` subshell. (*waiting for a bash specialist* :p)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `ksh`, `bash` and `zsh`, `time` is not a command (builtin or not), it's a reserved word in the language like `for` or `while`.

It's used to time a pipeline<sup>1</sup>.

In:

```
time for i in 1 2; do cmd1 "$i"; done | cmd2 > redir
```

You have special syntax that tells the shell to run that pipe line:

```
for i in 1 2; do cmd1 "$i"; done | cmd2 > redir
```

And report timing statistics for it.

In:

```
time cmd > output 2> error
```

It's the same, you're *timing* the `cmd > output 2> error` command, and the timing statistics still go on the shell's stderr.

You need:

```
{ time cmd > output 2> error; } 2> timing-output
```

Or:

```
exec 3>&2 2> timing-output
time cmd > output 2> error 3>&-
exec 2>&3 3>&-
```

For the shell's stderr to be redirected to `timing-output` before the time construct (again, not *command*) is used (here to time `cmd > output 2> error 3>&-`).

You can also run that `time` construct in a *subshell* that has its stderr redirected:

```
(time cmd > output 2> error) 2> timing-output
```

But that subshell is not necessary here, you only need stderr to be redirected at the time that `time` construct is invoked.

Most systems also have a `time` command. You can invoke that one by disabling the `time` keyword. All you need to do is quote that keyword somehow as keywords are only recognised as such when literal.

```
'time' cmd > output 2> error-and-timing-output
```

But beware the format may be different and the stderr of both `time` and `cmd` will be merged into `error-and-timing-output`.

Also, the `time` command, as opposed to the `time` construct cannot time pipelines or compound commands or functions or shell builtins...

If it were a builtin command, it might be able to time function invocations or builtins, but it could not time redirections or pipelines or compound commands.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that [`bash` has (what can be considered as) a bug](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/25026) whereby `time (cmd) 2> file` (but not `time cmd | (cmd2) 2> file` for instance) redirects the timing output to `file`</sub>

Comment: Well, I often stress my head to remember that `time` is a keyword, not a shell builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using `'time'` to get the executable-- handier than writing `/usr/bin/time` (or even `command time` :-)).

Comment: @alexis also `\time`.

Answer (score 7):

There's no command named `time wc`, `time` and `wc` are separated *word* in shell.

Now, there're often [two separate *program* named `time`, the one is shell keyword, another one is external command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86266/38906). In shells which `time` is a shell keyword, when you type `time wc ...`, the shell used its keyword `time` instead of the external [time utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html).

When the shell uses `time` keyword, it does not need to [fork()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) new process, the current `time` standard in and standard error are not changed. The redirection part in:

```
time wc file > wc.out 2>&1
```

affects `wc` only.

When you use [compound command `(list)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04):

```
(time wc file) > wc.out 2>&1
```

the shell ran `time wc file` inside a subshell, `(time wc file)` was considered a *single* command, and the redirection part affects its standard output and standard error, which now include both `time` and `wc`.

---

You can make the same effect, without the cost of forking new process by using another form of grouping command `{list;}`:

```
{time wc file;} > wc.out 2>&1
```

---

If you use external `time`, then you don't face this problem, because it was run in new process:

```
/usr/bin/time wc file > wc.out 2>&1
```

Comment: Is there any practical difference between using `time` and `/usr/bin/time`? Are the executables being called functionally the same?

Answer (score 2):

Because `time` you're executing is bash builtin. Bash processes it in such special way.

If you will use real `time` binary, it will act exactly in the way you expect it:

```
/usr/bin/time wc file > wc.out 2>&1
```

Though the output of this time is a bit different:

```
 $ /usr/bin/time wc file > wc.out 
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata1900maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+82minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: If it was a builtin, it wouldn't be a problem. The problem is that it's a _keyword_ in the language. `time cmd > output` times the `cmd > output` command, and `time foo | bar` times `foo | bar`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `time` that writes the time information. The builtin `time` makes the shell write this after the command has completed. But redirection affects only the command.

In the `(time ...)` case the redirection is applied to the whole subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Because time is a shell builtin, it writes to the *shell*'s stderr, rather than the command's stderr.

Using parentheses forces the whole command into a child shell whose stderr can be redirected.

using curly brackets produces a similar result without actually  starting a subshell

```
  { time who ; } > /tmp/timwho >& /tmp/xx
```

(yes, you need the semicolon)