# Looking for an external command that can do the same thing as echo

Tags: utilities, echo

`echo` is bash builtin. Is there an external command which can do the same thing as `echo`? (may do more)

Comment: `printf(1)` might also be handy for some needs.

Comment: When do you use builtin printf and when external printf?

Answer (score 5):

There's `echo`:

```
$ /bin/echo --version
echo (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Brian Fox and Chet Ramey.
```

Shell builtins which don't change the state of the shell are also often implemented as external commands - `[`/`test` is a famous one, so is `printf`:

```
$ /bin/printf --version
printf (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

If you have `busybox`, it is also likely to support `echo`:

```
$ busybox echo --version
--version
```

Comment: Thanks. What are the differences between the two, in purposes and in ways for usage?

Comment: @Tim No difference in purpose. They may accept different flags - check the manpage on your system to know for sure.

Comment: How do you invoke `echo` as an external command? Full path? (can it be less complex?)

Comment: @Tim try some of the methods given in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86266/70524