# Differences between reserved word and command `time` on shell builtin, function, pipeline and command list?

Tags: bash, time-utility

In the Bash Reference Manual,

> The use of `time` as a reserved word permits the timing of **shell builtins**, **shell functions**, and **pipelines**. An external
>       `time` command cannot time these easily.

1. Could you explain why the quote says that?

   Is this because of the difference between a reserved word and a
   command, not just limited to the case of `time`? For example, how does the bash shell
   parse or interpret them differently?

   Or is this only limited to the case of `time`?
2. In the following examples,

   why does the external `time` work on a shell builtin, and a
   pipeline, while the quote say it "cannot time these easily"?

   External `time` on **a shell builtin**:

   ```
   $ /usr/bin/time echo hello
   hello
   0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1676maxresident)k
   0inputs+0outputs (0major+78minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   ```

   External `time` on **a pipeline**:

   ```
   $ /usr/bin/time sleep 10 | sleep 5
   0.00user 0.00system 0:10.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1776maxresident)k
   0inputs+0outputs (0major+79minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   ```
3. In the following example, why does the external `time` on **a shell
   function** fail? What does its error output mean?

   ```
   $ function mytest () { sleep 10; }

   $ /usr/bin/time mytest
   /usr/bin/time: cannot run mytest: No such file or directory
   Command exited with non-zero status 127
   0.00user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1252maxresident)k
   32inputs+0outputs (0major+30minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   ```
4. It seems that the quote does not just apply to timing shell builtins,
   shell functions, and pipelines, [but also to timing **a group of
   commands**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/make-bash-use-external-time-command-rather-than-shell-built-in#comment128553_86269):

   ```
   $ time { echo hello; sleep 3; echo tim; }
   hello
   tim

   real    0m3.002s
   user    0m0.000s
   sys 0m0.000s


   $ /usr/bin/time { echo hello; sleep 3; echo tim; }
   bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
   ```

   Why does the shell say "bash: syntax error near unexpected token
   `}`" in the case for command `/usr/bin/time`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between keyword, reserved word, and builtin?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267761/differences-between-keyword-reserved-word-and-builtin)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, `time` is a [reserved word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-reserved-word), so the shell can parse it the own way and apply rules for it.

[Here is the code show how `bash` parse line start with `time` reserved word](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/y.tab.c#n5110):

```
static int
time_command_acceptable ()
{
#if defined (COMMAND_TIMING)
  int i;

  if (posixly_correct && shell_compatibility_level > 41)
    {
      /* Quick check of the rest of the line to find the next token.  If it
     begins with a `-', Posix says to not return `time' as the token.
     This was interp 267. */
      i = shell_input_line_index;
      while (i < shell_input_line_len && (shell_input_line[i] == ' ' || shell_input_line[i] == '\t'))
        i++;
      if (shell_input_line[i] == '-')
    return 0;
    }

  switch (last_read_token)
    {
    case 0:
    case ';':
    case '\n':
    case AND_AND:
    case OR_OR:
    case '&':
    case WHILE:
    case DO:
    case UNTIL:
    case IF:
    case THEN:
    case ELIF:
    case ELSE:
    case '{':       /* } */
    case '(':       /* )( */
    case ')':       /* only valid in case statement */
    case BANG:      /* ! time pipeline */
    case TIME:      /* time time pipeline */
    case TIMEOPT:   /* time -p time pipeline */
    case TIMEIGN:   /* time -p -- ... */
      return 1;
    default:
      return 0;
    }
#else
  return 0;
#endif /* COMMAND_TIMING */
}
```

You see, `time` can be followed by most others `bash` reserved words.

In case of external command, the normal rule was applied, `{` was considered input of `/usr/bin/time`. `}` alone is invalid token, and `bash` raise the error.

---

In:

```
/usr/bin/time echo hello
```

external `time` did not call the shell builtin `echo` but the external `echo` command.

A `strace` verifies that:

```
$ strace -fe execve /usr/bin/time echo 1
execve("/usr/bin/time", ["/usr/bin/time", "echo", "1"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
Process 25161 attached
....
[pid 25161] execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "1"], [/* 64 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 25161] execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "1"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
1
[pid 25161] +++ exited with 0 +++
....
```

Here external `time` lookup your `PATH` variable to find the command executable. That also explain in case of using a function, you got *No such file or directory* becasue there's no command named `mytest` in your `PATH`.

Comment: "time is a reverse word". really?

Comment: @BinaryZebra: And also, feel free to make the editing next time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Cuonglm. I just added some details to my questions.

Comment: thanks. "In case of external command, the normal rule was applied", what is the "normal rule"? Why is `{` considered input of `/usr/bin/time`, and `}` alone invalid token,?

Comment: I tried to find it in POSIX specifications, but can't find any.

Comment: @Tim: The normal rule means how the shell, in this case `bash`, parse the line.

Answer (score 1):

In 2. you can see the output is wrong, especially for the second case: `/usr/bin/time` times the first command of the pipeline (10 s). Then the `/usr/bin/time sleep 10` command output is piped into `sleep 5`. It is the shell that breaks down your command-line this way: for it, `/usr/bin/time` is just like any other command.

In 3. shell functions are internal to the shell process: `/usr/bin/time` is invoked with argument `mytest`, it searches this command in the path, and finds nothing. `/usr/bin/time` is invoked by the shell but is not part of it.