# Why full path to /usr/bin/time affects output?

Tags: shell-script, time-utility

I am running very simple command:

```
[tester@centos-lvm ~]$ time cal > /dev/null

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

However, if I specify full path to the `time` executable I get different output:

```
[tester@centos-lvm ~]$ /usr/bin/time cal > /dev/null
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 928maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+272minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I believe when I run `time` (without path) the `/usr/bin/time` is actually executed:

```
[tester@centos-lvm ~]$ which time
/usr/bin/time
```

`man time` tells that there are two different output formats, the `-p` option chooses between them. But I have not specified any options! I checked aliases, nothing there about time.

This behavior is quite unexpected and very strange. Could someone explain why and how this happens?

Comment: Try `type -a time` instead of `which time`.

Comment: [Deeply relevant, but not strictly a duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269795/differences-between-reserved-word-and-command-time-on-shell-builtin-function) (also several other related questions from the sidebar there)

Comment: One `time` is shell command another is executable program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `time` without a path, it's likely that you use a utility that is provided to you by a shell built-in (see the manual for your particular shell). When specifying a path, you are definitely using an external utility.

These two may differ in their implementation and in what output they produce.